# sql query- Most common array element from a column with different arrays

Tags: mysql, sql

hello i am stuck at a problem, i have database where i have a column [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Ipp.png) whose name is "tileused". it has tile names separated by "," comma. I need to display list of all tile names with their count in desc order.

for eg:

column name: tileused

And single cell looks like this: 

*"Antarca Rose Decor 2_90_30_Matt_AGL Official_patterned_1395.jpg,Antarca White_90_30_Matt_AGL Official.jpg,Antarca White_90_30_Matt_AGL Official.jpg,Antarca Rose Decor 3_90_30_Matt_AGL Official_patterned_1395.jpg,Antarca White_90_30_Matt_AGL Official.jpg,Antarca White_90_30_Matt_AGL Official.jpg,Satin Bianco_30_30_Matt_AGL.jpg"*

all tile names separated by "," comma.

I need result as

```html
<html>
<body>
<table width="" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th> tile name </th>
<th> count </th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Antarca Rose Decor 2_90_30_Matt_AGL Official_patterned_1395.jpg</td>
<td>1300</td></tr>
</body>
</table>
```

so far i have seen this solution, but haven't worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450240/9510852

If you can help me, it would be great.
thanks in advance

full view of table[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj0Qu.png)

Comment: When you say "single cell" what are you referring to?

Comment: Storing a comma-separated list of values in a column is very bad database design. With such a poor design, working with the data is very difficult.

Comment: @Nick that is database cell. the column "tileused" has 1 of the entry as: single cell.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson What could be the better design for this.

Comment: Can you post the entire table structure? It's difficult to solve the problem without it.

Comment: @Nick added , kindly check

Comment: I don't see any columns related to tiles in that image?

Comment: 12th column "tileused"

Comment: @Nick https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj0Qu.png

Comment: Ok, so where is the column which contains the comma separated list of tiles?

Comment: @Nick that's the column "tileused"

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. Is there a column which just has the individual tile names in it?

Comment: yes, but why would that help ?